# How to read data from sensor from separate class

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors

I have a problem with code. I have two classes: MainActivity where i checking if sensor (in this case light sensor) is available and if yes - i try to get date from sensor from another class LightSensor, but result is always null. I think that i'm doing something wrong with listener but i don't know what.. and i'm sitting on this couple of hours and still nothing.. If you have any idea, please write and help me.

MainActivity class:

```
`public class MainActivity extends Activity implements EventListener {

    SensorManager mSensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView wyswietl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        LightSensor mLightSensor = new LightSensor(getBaseContext());

        if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) != null){
            //mLightSensor.register();
            String newLux = mLightSensor.getLux();
            wyswietl.setText("Light level: " + newLux);
        }
        else{

        }
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }`
```

and in MainActivioty class i don't know it argument in constructor :
    `LightSensor mLightSensor = new LightSensor(getBaseContext());` is good...

LightSensor class:

```
`public class LightSensor implements SensorEventListener {

    public SensorManager mSensorManagerx;
    public Sensor lightManager;
    public String lux;
    Context context;

    public LightSensor(Context context){
    //public void onCreateLight(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        mSensorManagerx = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        lightManager = mSensorManagerx.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT); 
    }

    public void register(){
        mSensorManagerx.registerListener(this, lightManager, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lux = Float.toString(event.values[0]);  
    }
    public String getLux(){
        return lux;
    }

    public void unregister(){
        mSensorManagerx.unregisterListener(this);
    }

}`
```

Comment: you don't give the system the opportunity to call `onSensorChanged`. You don't call `register`, and you don't check that `lux` has been set.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a `getter` for this purpose, because the value your getting will be initialized after a **unknown time**. So it could still be null when you're calling the `getLux` method.

What you should do is use a **listener pattern**. I have changed your code a bit to give you an example implementation.

**LightSensor:**

```
public class LightSensor implements SensorEventListener {

    public static interface LightSensorListener {
        abstract void onLightSensorChanged(String lux);
    }

    private LightSensorListener listener;

    private SensorManager mSensorManagerx;
    private Sensor lightManager;

    public LightSensor(Context context) {
        mSensorManagerx = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        lightManager = mSensorManagerx.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    }

    public void setListener(LightSensorListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public boolean register() {
        return mSensorManagerx.registerListener(this, lightManager, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onLightSensorChanged(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
        }
    }

    public void unregister() {
        mSensorManagerx.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class ActivityLightSensor extends Activity implements LightSensorListener {

    private TextView text;
    private LightSensor mLightSensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);

        mLightSensor = new LightSensor(getBaseContext());
        mLightSensor.setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLightSensorChanged(String lux){
        text.setText("Light level: " + lux);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onStart();
        if(!mLightSensor.register()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Light sensor not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onStop();
        mLightSensor.unregister();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But something is still wrong, because phone doesn't show text or result.. it is empty field on screen

Comment: Did you register the Light sensor in the onStart method of your activity?

Comment: Should I call onLightSensorChanged(argument) in OnCreate method? with what argument?

Comment: See the updated code, especially the onResume method where it checks if the sensor is supported ;)

Comment: No you should never call that method yourself!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer that helped you. As it could help others. Use the check-mark on the top-left of the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

onSensorChanged event is not called just after you created listener. It is called after something will change sensot value, then it will be called. So you should implement some callback, or, as for me, better would be to implement SensorEventListener in your activity, then just in onSensorChanged event method call

```
wyswietl.setText("Light level: " + newLux);
```

Comment: Can you write for me this line of code? Unfortunetelly I don't understand you